# New template opencart

Tags: templates, download, opencart

I have 2 websites made with OpenCart cms, the first one is in opencart version 1.5.5.1 and the second one is in opencart version 2.0.2.0. I don't know really how it works, some people put it for me for the two first website.

I want to buy a new template in opencart for a new website, do I have to take into consideration that I already have two opencart versions or is it a new process? Does it means that when I buy a new template, its gonna be downloaded automatically?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open cart templates are already set according to their versions. All you have to do is to download the template for 1.5 or 2.0 and put them in the view folder, go to super admin and select the theme. That's all. It's as easy as you like it.